# Writing file into hdfs from spark rdd

Tags: list, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am trying to write the elements of sparkrdd into hdfs filesystem.
Particular RDD is of type RDD[List(String)]

So in the file am getting the output like
List(6, 125, 6988, 2021-10-01, ST, LENS)

How could I save this as shown below?
6, 125, 6988, 2021-10-01, ST, LENS

Comment: save it where ?

Comment: You need to transform your RDD to RDD[String]. Something like `rdd.map(x => x.mkstring(", "))`